# inject javascript in cshtml from partial-view using RenderSection not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view, that requires some javascript at the bottom of the page.

The main page:

```
...some html...
<div>
@Html.Partial("_myPartial")
</div>

....more html....

//required JS at BOTTOM -  THIS should also come from above partial
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

my partial view:

```
<div id="Slider">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[img 1]" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[img 2]" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[img 3]" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[img 4]" />
</div>


@section scripts
{
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function () {
    $('#Slider').orbit();
  });
  </script>
}
```

But this does not work - the scripts section is not included.

I googled, this is not supported...well...

...How would YOU handle this situation??

Suggestions were to make yet another partial with the script and include this....
Not pretty!

Is there a better approach out there??

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source of the rendered page. Is the problem that your script comes out before the definition of jQuery?

Your default _Layout.cshtml probably has...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
...
@RenderBody()
...
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts")
@RenderSection("scripts", required:false)
...
</html>
```

You need to tell MVC to put your script after the scripts bundle. In your DoStuff.cshtml,

```
...
@using (Html.BeginForm()){ //this bit is in the body of the page 
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.NewSalary)
    <input type="submit" data-confirmprompt='are you sure?' />
}
...

@section scripts{ //this bit will end up in the scripts section
<script type="text/javascript">
    //http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2010/12/16/using-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery-to-create-confirmation-prompts.aspx
    //cunning script so you can say 

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('*[data-confirmprompt]').click(function (event) {
            var promptText = $(this).attr('data-confirmprompt');
            if (!confirm(promptText)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just include it in your partial, it will then be executed, leave out the `$(window).load`:

```
<div id="Slider">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[img 1]" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[img 2]" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[img 3]" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x400&text=[img 4]" />
</div>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Slider').orbit();
  </script>
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this and it didn't work: simply the JS is not added to the page and therefore not executed.